# Observable<Object> to Observable<Array<Object>>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have **HttpClient.post** request. I pass *id* in the body and it returns **Observable< Object >**.
It works fine.

```
let obj: Observable<Object> = []
let IDs = [1, 2, 3]
for (const id of IDs) {
    obj.push(httpClient.post('/api/object', { id: id })
  }
```

But I need to call it many times with different *id*.
How can I rewrite my code to return **Observable< Array< Object > >** for the same API ?

Comment: For starters, what *is* your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `forkJoin` operator from 'rxjs' in order to achieve this. You can pass in an array of `HttpClient.post` observables and it will return an Observable of an array of result objects, once all calls have completed.

Here is a code example:

```
const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const result$ = forkJoin(
  ids.map((id) => this.http.post<Result>(`yoururl/objects/${id}`, {}))
);
```

In this case `result$` will be an observable that emits one array of type `Result` once all post requests have completed.